# Does an instruction of sleep thread or process continues its execution while the thread/process is slept?

Tags: c++, c

When i do my assignment on IPC(Inter Process Communication),a chat application using shared memory between two process,how does a sleep thread checks the condition in the while loop(if *shm != 1 the thread prints the string wakeup) how can is this possible?

```
#define TRUE 1

while(*shm == 1)
    sleep(1)
printf("wakeup");
```

Comment: It’s not clear what you’re asking. Your sleep time is very very short. Really just enough to give processor priority to other threads. After a very very short sleep time, it wakes, checks the *while* condition and continues accordingly.

Comment: if you're doing IPC, you'll certainly want an inter-process mutex around the test in this process and the write in the other

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sleep` doesn't check `shm` value.

Right now your thread calls `sleep`, it will suspend the thread just for a few miliseconds, and then it will be woken up by a signal from OS timer/scheduler. That's all that `sleep` does. Then the thread wakes up and resumes your code: sleep() returns, loop starts next iteration, checks `shm` and makes a decision whether to sleep again or continue.

It works, but consumes more than it could if you've used specialized synchronization primitives - like condition variables in c++11/posix. Sleeping while waiting for condition variable signal will truly sleep until signal is received, without wasting cpu cycles for such periodical wake-ups.

Comment: Thank you @Vlad. So when the scheduler allocates the CPU for the slept process,it resumes its execution and at that time it checks the condition in the while loop.

Comment: Please feel free to rollback if you think I changed too much., I wanted to expand the 'ms' abbreviation and then forgot it's not my answer, sorry about that:)

Comment: @quetzalcoatl, thx, I'm ok with everything that makes stackoverflow better :)

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned int sleep(unsigned int seconds);
```

> Suspends thread execution for a specified number of seconds. Because
>   of processor delays, the thread can sleep slightly longer than this
>   specified time. An unblocked signal received during this time (for
>   which the action is to invoke a signal handler function or to end the
>   thread) “wakes up” the thread prematurely. When that function returns,
>   sleep() returns immediately even if there is sleep time remaining.

So your `while(*shm == 1)` doesn't calcs while thread sleeps.